# Reduce size of PrimeNg Library with Angular Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng

PrimeNg is a big library containing many components. My angular application is using only few components out of it.
And I am using AngularCLI to build this application.
When I build it, vendor.bundle has entire content of primeng library. This makes huge size of bundle size (~4MB).

How can I include only necessary components instead of full library?

Comment: Please provide modules where you are using primeng components.

Comment: For example I am just using DataTable component in my angular app  (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally we import PrimeNg component using following syntax

`import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';`

When we refer to this common namespace, it pulls entire library in vendor.bundle.js

Instead of this, pull it from specific module,
`import { DataTableModule,  } from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/components/common/shared';`

This will just include referred component (+ their dependencies) in vendor.bundle.js

To find your relevant path, download PrimeNg Code (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng) and check list of components listed in "primeng.d.ts" file.

Comment: great answer... save a day for me.

Comment: probably no longer relevant, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806817/is-the-entirety-of-primeng-imported-when-you-use-it-or-is-it-tree-shaken-how-c

Comment: @eugen you are right, they (primeng) have updated their documentation e.g. https://primeng.org/checkbox where they are indicating to import what is needed